# how to mount this disk?

Tags: filesystems, mount

I'm trying to mount a disc created some time ago in Amazon EC2. This is what I see (line breaks added for the sake of readability):

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/xvda4
/dev/xvda4: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0x83, starthead 1, 
startsector 63, 10474317 sectors, extended partition table (last)\011, 
code offset 0x0
```

When I'm trying to mount it:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/xvda4 /mnt/foo
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvda4,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

How can I mount this disc?

Maybe this information will help:

```
$ sudo fdisk -lu /dev/xvda4
Disk /dev/xvda4: 5368 MB, 5368709120 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 652 cylinders, total 10485760 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0952616d
  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda4p1              63    10474379     5237158+  83  Linux
```

Answer (score 5):

Post by [Fernandez de Quilon](http://www.jefferyfernandez.id.au/2007/06/14/mounting-partitions-that-are-within-a-disk-image/) helped me:

```
$ mount -t ext4 -o offset=32256 /dev/xvda4 /mnt/foo
```

Works fine. `32256` is calculated as `63` (start of partition) multiplied by `512` (sector size).

Comment: Why did you not just use the `/dev/xvda4p1` device node to automatically hook up to the inner partition?

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to mount an old snapshot you are probably getting a uuid error. Check if

```
 dmesg | tail
```

Shows:

```
[-your.timestamp.here-] XFS (xvdg): Filesystem has duplicate UUID - can't mount
```

If it does, and you only need to mount to get something off of it you can mount it like this (on /var/www2 in my case):

```
mount -o nouuid /dev/xvdg /var/www2
```

If you want to use it regularly you need to generate a new UUID like this (on my /dev/xvdg which you should replace with your /dev/...):

```
xfs_admin -U generate /dev/xvdg
```

Answer (score 3):

`/dev/xvda4` does not contain a filesystem, as the output of `file` indicates. It contains a partition table. `fdisk` displays this partition table. There is presumably a filesystem on the sole partition inside that volume (the name of the partition is visible in the `fdisk` output).

```
sudo mount /dev/xvda4p1 /mnt/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming /dev/xvda is the device, and /dev/xvda4 is a partition.  With a partition table in a partition, this complicates things a bit.  But we can get around that using the loopback device which would normally be used to mount filesystems residing in files.  But we can apply it to a device, too.

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset=32256 /dev/xvda4 /mnt/foo
```

The number 32256 is the number of bytes to sector 63 where your fdisk output showed the inner partition to be starting at.

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
# mount -t auto /dev/xvda4 /mnt/foo
```

Comment: The same response as above. If `-t` is not specified it is assumed as `auto` (according to `mount` man page)